# Will lock() statement block all threads in the process/appdomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Maybe the question sounds silly, but I don't understand 'something about threads and locking and I would like to get a confirmation ([here's why I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989520/queue-access-to-the-database-to-avoid-multiple-cache-items)).

So, if I have 10 servers and 10 request in the same time come to each server, that's 100 request across the farm. Without locking, thats 100 request to the database.

If I do something like this:

```
private static readonly object myLockHolder = new object();
if (Cache[key] == null)
{
   lock(myLockHolder)
   {
      if (Cache[key] == null)
      {
         Cache[key] = LengthyDatabaseCall();
      }
   }
}
```

How many database requests will I do? 10? 100? Or as much as I have threads?

Comment: Thank you all for excellent explanations, I tested it and it works as you all suggested - 10 db requests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a hierarchy of objects:

- You have servers (10)
- On each server you have processes (probably only 1 - your service/app pool)
- In each process you have threads (probably many)

Your code will **only** prohibit threads within the same process on the same server access to modify the `Cache` object simultaneously. You can create locks across processes and even across servers, but the cost increases a lot as you move up the hierarchy.

Using the `lock` statement does not actually *lock* any threads. However, if one thread is executing code inside the lock (that is in the block of code following the `lock` statement) any other thread that wants to take the lock and execute the same code has to wait until the first thread holding the lock leaves the block of code and releases the lock.

The C# `lock` statement uses a Windows [critical section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530(v=VS.85).aspx) which a lightweight locking mechanism. If you want to lock across processes you can use a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) instead. To lock across servers you can use a database or a shared file.

As dkackman has pointed out .NET has the concept of an AppDomain that is a kind of lightweight process. You can have multiple AppDomains per process. The C# `lock` statement only locks a resource within a single AppDomain, and a proper description of the hierarchy would include the AppDomain below the process and above the threads. However, quite often you only have a single AppDomain in a process making the distinction somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: Slight correction "Your code will only prohibit threads within the same AppDomain". C# statics are bound to an AppDomain, not a process.

Answer (score 2):

The C# `lock` statement locks on a particular instance of an object (the object you created with `new object()`). Objects are (in most cases) not shared across AppDomains, thus if you are having 10 servers, 10 threads can run concurrently access your database with that piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Lock is not blocking threads.
It is locking some instance of an object. And each thread which tries to access it is blocked.
So in your case each thread which will try to access myLockHolder will be locked and not all the threads.
In other words we can say that [Lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.10).aspx) is syntactic sugar for using [Critical Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530(VS.10).aspx).

Like you can see in MSDN :

> lock(expression) statement block
>
> where:
>
> ***expression*** Specifies the object that you want to lock on.  expression must
>   be a reference type. Typically,
>   expression will either be this, if you
>   want to protect an instance variable,
>   or typeof(class), if you want to
>   protect a static variable (or if the
>   critical section occurs in a static
>   method in the given class).
>
> ***statement block*** The statements of the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

`lock` will block all threads in that application from accessing the myLockHolder object.

So if you have 10 instances of the application running you'll get 10 requests to the server while the object is locked on each.  The moment you exit the lock statement, the next request will process in that application, but as long as `Cache[key]` is not `null`, it won't access the database..

The number of actual requests you get depends on what happens here:

```
  if (Cache[key] == null)
  {
     Cache[key] = LengthyDatabaseCall();
  }
```

If `LengthyDatabaseCall();` fails, the next request will try and access the database server and retrieve the information as well, so really your best case scenario is that there will only be 10 requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Only the threads that need access to your shared variable at the moment another thread is using it will go into a wait state.

how many that is at any give time is hard to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB will get 10 requests, with odds being good that requests 2-10 run much faster than request 1.