# Ensure concurrent (money) transactions in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, transactions, atomic

Assume I have an `account_profile` table, which has `Score` field that is similar to an account's money (the database type is `BIGINT(20)` and the EntityFramework type is `long`, because I don't need decimal). Now I have the following function:

```
public long ChangeScoreAmount(int userID, long amount)
{
    var profile = this.Entities.account_profile.First(q => q.AccountID == userID);

    profile.Score += amount;

    this.Entities.SaveChanges();

    return profile.Score;
}
```

However, I afraid that when `ChangeScoreAmount` are called multiple times concurrently, the final amount won't be correct.

Here are my current solutions I am thinking of:

- Adding a lock with a static locking variable in the `ChangeScoreAmount` function, since the class itself may be instantiated multiple times when needed. It looks like this:

  ```
  public long ChangeScoreAmount(int userID, long amount)
  {
      lock (ProfileBusiness.scoreLock)
      {
          var profile = this.Entities.account_profile.First(q => q.AccountID == userID);

          profile.Score += amount;

          this.Entities.SaveChanges();

          return profile.Score;
      }
  }
  ```

The problem is, I have never tried a lock on `static` variable, so I don't know if it is really safe and if any deadlock would occur. Moreover, it may be bad if somewhere else outside this function, a change to `Score` field is applied midway.

**OK this is no longer an option, because my server application will be run on multiple sites, that means the locking variable cannot be used**

- Creating a Stored Procedure in the database and call that Stored procedure in the function. However, I don't know if there is an "atomic" way to create that Store Procedure, so that it can only be called once at a time, since I still need to retrieve the value, changing it then update it again?

I am using MySQL Community 5.6.24 and MySQL .NET Connector 6.9.6 in case it matters.

**NOTE** My server application may be runned on multiple server machines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [acquiring a lock on a static object should block on other request threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681725/acquiring-a-lock-on-a-static-object-should-block-on-other-request-threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sql transactions with repeatable read isolation level instead of locking on the application. For example you can write

```
public long ChangeScoreAmount(int userID, long amount)
{
    using(var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
        new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead })
    {
      var profile = this.Entities.account_profile.First(q => q.AccountID == userID);

      profile.Score += amount;

      this.Entities.SaveChanges();

      ts.Complete();

      return profile.Score;
    }    
}
```

Transaction garantees that accountprofile record will not changed in db while you aren't commit or rollback.

Comment: Is it applied when my server have multiple application instance, or when my application is being runned on multiple server machines? I believe that the code is server side outside the database?

Comment: It's no matter how many application instances or server machines you have. Transaction live in database and database engine prevent any changes(from another transactions) to record that was readed in your transaction with repeatable read isolation level.

Comment: Can I have one more question please, the `TransactionScope` has neither `Connection` nor `Entities` object in the parameters, how do it know what to "isolate" and "live in the database and database engine"? What "if" I have two database connections working at the same time?

Comment: After creating instance of TransactionScope you can access current Transaction in the current thread via static property of Transaction class - Transaction.Current.
When ado.net command executes it looks at Transaction.Current and it's isolation level then pass begin transaction command to database.
If you have two db connection in the same thread then all commands executing on them will be part of one distributed transaction. For more information here http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c10993/SystemTransactions-Implement-Your-Own-Resource-Manager.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, make sense to me now!